# Oracle: Is there a simple way to say "if null keep the current value" in merge/update statements?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a rather weak understanding of any of oracle's more advanced functionality but this should I think be possible.

Say I have a table with the following schema:

```
MyTable
  Id INTEGER,
  Col1 VARCHAR2(100),
  Col2 VARCHAR2(100)
```

I would like to write an sproc with the following

```
PROCEDURE InsertOrUpdateMyTable(p_id in integer, p_col1 in varcahr2, p_col2 in varchar2)
```

Which, in the case of an update will, if the value in p_col1, p_col2 is null will not overwrite Col1, Col2 respectively

So If I have a record:

```
id=123, Col1='ABC', Col2='DEF'

exec InsertOrUpdateMyTable(123, 'XYZ', '098'); --results in id=123, Col1='XYZ', Col2='098'
exec InsertOrUpdateMyTable(123, NULL, '098');  --results in id=123, Col1='ABC', Col2='098'
exec InsertOrUpdateMyTable(123, NULL, NULL);   --results in id=123, Col1='ABC', Col2='DEF'
```

Is there any simple way of doing this without having multiple SQL statements?

I am thinking there might be a way to do this with the Merge statement though I am only mildly familiar with it.

---

**EDIT:**
Cade Roux bellow suggests using COALESCE which works great!  [Here are some examples of using the coalesce kewyord.](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Oracle/Conversion-Functions/COALESCEreturnsthefirstnonnullexpressionintheexpressionlist.htm)
And here is the solution for my problem:

```
MERGE INTO MyTable mt
    USING (SELECT 1 FROM   DUAL) a
    ON (mt.ID = p_id)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE
           SET mt.Col1 = coalesce(p_col1, mt.Col1), mt.Col2 = coalesce(p_col2, mt.Col2)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (ID, Col1, Col2)
        VALUES (p_id, p_col1, p_col2);
```

Comment: I think the MERGE statement wrapper is only obscuring things here. In such a one-row merge, I would keep the update separate and trap a "if sql%notfound then insert" following it.

Comment: @Nick: you are better off with the merge.  Someone else can mess with your data between two SQL statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using MERGE and COALESCE?  [Try this link for an example](http://blogs.oracle.com/cmar/entry/using_merge_to_do_an)

with

```
SET a.Col1 = COALESCE(incoming.Col1, a.Col1)
    ,a.Col2 = COALESCE(incoming.Col2, a.Col2)
```

Comment: How do I do this?!  Please tell me.

Comment: Shouldn't this be the other way around? COALESCE will return the first non-null value so in this case once a value is set to something it will never be set to anything else.

I think the nvl statement is more precise in this context.

Comment: Yes, I will correct my code to reverse the parameters.  NVL() is the same as COALESCE() for two values (at least in SQL Server ISNULL() is the same as COALESCE()).

Answer (score 2):

Change the call or the update statement to use

```
nvl(newValue, oldValue)
```

for the new field value.

Comment: But then I have to get the oldValue out in another SQL statement, unless you know something I don't